# Set both Date and Time for AlarmManager in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to set specific Date and time to fire notification for Alarm Manager. I found a useful code that can show both Date Fragment and Time Fragment.My problem is when I set the alarm,the notification didn't pop up at the specified date and time and instead it pop up immediately. Please help me Seniors out there.

Here is my codes.

For open time picker

```
mOpenTimePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar date;
            final Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            date = Calendar.getInstance();
            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    date.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                            date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                            date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                            Log.v(TAG, "The choosen one " + date.getTime());

                        }
                    }, currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();
                }
            }, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentDate.get(Calendar.DATE)).show();
            DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
            mTextView.setText(dateFormat.format(date.getTime()));
            startAlarm(date);
        }


    });
```

For Start Alarm

```
 private void startAlarm(Calendar c) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //Passing data
        String title = mTitle.getText().toString();
        String message = mMessage.getText().toString();

        id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("Title", title);
        intent.putExtra("Message", message);
        intent.putExtra("ID", id);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for setting Alarm inside `onClick(View v)` will call immediately because its written synchronously. It can be solved by :-

```
mOpenTimePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar date;
            final Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            date = Calendar.getInstance();
            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    date.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                            date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                            date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                            // Set the alarm here
                            DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
                            mTextView.setText(dateFormat.format(date.getTime()));
                            startAlarm(date);
                        }
                    }, currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();
                }
            }, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentDate.get(Calendar.DATE)).show();
        }
    });
```

This code is bit messy So probably create a separate method for opening `TimePicker` and `DatePicker` .

Comment: Thank for your solution bro.It really solved my problem.And also thank for your suggestion @ADM.

Comment: @ADM.Done bro.Sorry for late.I didnt know how to accept the answer .That is why.